# In GTK how do I wait for a button to be pressed while allowing the main loop to continue?

Tags: c, gtk, scheduling

I'm writing a Z80 simulator with a GUI running on GTK (https://github.com/clancyj4/z80sim/tree/dev for those interested).

My problem is that I need to trap the IN opcode and allow a window to be edited to provide the IO codes.  Let me show you what I've got so far:

```
/* get a byte (char?) from the input part of the Port window */
/* What we really want to do is have a queue */

BYTE IOPort_IN(int port)
{
  char whole_buffer[IOINBUFLEN * 4];            /* 4x in case of Hex */
  BYTE c;
  int i;

  if (IOPort[port] == NULL)                             /* struct exists? */
    Create_IOPort_Struct(port);

  printf("IOPort_IN: port=%d in_len=%d in_ptr=%d\n",
        port, IOPort[port]->in_len, IOPort[port]->in_ptr);

  if (IOPort[port]->in_len == 0)
  {
    sprintf(tstr, "Port %d requires input", port);
    Add_to_Log(tstr);
    show_log(TRUE);
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(inportprompt_textbuffer, "Input Required", -1);

/* somehow keep the gtk main loop running so the interface updates and allows the editing of the ioportin_textbuffer,
but wait for the input submission button the be pressed */

    i = gtk_text_buffer_get_char_count(ioportin_textbuffer);
    printf("in port buff len is %d.\n", i);
  }

  return(c);
}
```

The trapping of the opcode is OK and this function is called.  The trouble is that I have no idea how to implement the comment in the middle.

The aim is to have the rest of the simulation on hold, but with the GTK main loop still running, so the Log window etc get updated and I can enter a string in the IO window.  But it waits until a submit button is pressed.  I can freeze the Z80 simulation by setting a flag, so that's no problem.

I have a nasty feeling that I haven't expressed the problem very well, so please bear with me and ask any questions that would clarify the situation.

Cheers,

Justin.

Comment: Unrelated, but why `* 4` instead of `* 2`? One byte is at most two hex digits.

Comment: Actually, it should be * 3 (accounting for the space between hex digits).  I have no idea why I elected for 4.  Corrected.

Comment: Interesting question. I do have problem understanding your question. 1) What is text_buffer for? 2) Why  wait for the input submission button? What happens after button is pressed? Does it unpause simulation? 3) Where does simulation run? In the same thread, or another one? If in the same thread, will it cause the user interface hangs? 4) What does `IOPort_IN` return? Instead of replying to my comment, it would be nice if you can edit your question to help me understand better. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I sidestepped the issue and forced a return of 00 if there wasn't an input queue already in place.  With plenty of warnings, of course.

I would still like to know how to get GTK to hold execution on the main thread until a sub-window has been activated.  When I know, I'll put the answer in here.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit unclear. This will setup the callback for a function, it will call whatever function you pass through it.

```
void button_connect_callback(GtkWidget *button, void *button_callback)
{
g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_callback), NULL);
}
```

I have some tutorials that might be of help [here](https://github.com/TerrehDactyl)